# Software for Live Video Overlays

Tags: video-editor

I have recently been working with a trial of Boinx TV, but would like to go pro. I am trying to create a live overlay with a logo, weather, and some live RSS feeds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Video Production. As it stands this question is too broad to answer. Please edit your question and explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into Open Broadcaster Software. You may need some third-party plugins to get all the features you want, but it's a great place to start looking.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before ***[Open Broadcast Software](https://obsproject.com/)*** and or ***[XSplit](https://www.xsplit.com/)*** seems to be the standards. Both are fully functional with plugins to customize your live stream output. Though OBS is free to use and available of multiple platforms while XSplit has three different range for pricing depending on the functionalities you intend to use during production. For a more complete comparison between the two software please visit ***[here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/obs-vs-xsplit/)***.